# Accesing individual properties of an Object inside subscribe function in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, observable, subscribe

I have a working api that returns an array of table entity objects on query . this is the corresponding tableEntity in my angular app

```
export interface TableEntity {
    partitionKey: string;
    rowKey: string;
    ownerid: string;
    filetype: string;
    companyName: string;
    parentID: string;
    isdirectory: boolean;
    filesize: Int32Array;
}
```

In my angular app I am querying this api using a service and this is the relevant code that contacts the api and sends the table entity objects to a component

```
getFileStructureData(){
   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'list').pipe(
     map((user: TableEntity) => {
       return user;
     })
   )
```

Now inside a component I am able to access this object , and it returns array of objects as expected when i console log this object.

```
this.TableService.getFileStructureData().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response);
    }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                })
```

but when i try to console log the individual properties of the object ,

```
this.TableService.getFileStructureData().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.companyName);
    }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                })
```

I get value as undefined in the console log . How can i access the individual properties of tableEntity object inside the subscribe function?  many thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you’re not getting an array of entities?

Comment: "it returns array of objects as expected". `map((user: TableEntity) => {` would be incorrect then, it would need to be `map((users: TableEntity[]) => {` or similar right? As in an array of users. Also, also that map isn't doing anything, you can simply `return this.http.get< TableEntity[]>(this.baseUrl + 'list')`.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `.companyName` property. You could try `response.length` if you want to print out one of its properties. If you want the `companyName` of the first `TableEntity` in your response array, you could try `console.log(response[0].companyName)`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need `pipe()` inside `getFileStructureData`, you can just do:

```
getFileStructureData(){
   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'list')
)
```

And your response is probably and array of objects, try something like:

```
this.TableService.getFileStructureData().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response[0].companyName);
    }, error => {console.log(error);})
```